# How to check files against TFS without getting latest?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

While reconciling an old solution I have been getting historical file versions from TFS without checking out.
That is, for a bunch of files in my solution I did "Show History" > "Get This Version"

Now I have all the mix-and-match of historical versions I want, but I did not keep track of which files (and which versions of the files) I got which were not latest.

Is there a way I can get a list of "not latest" files in my solution? That is, I want the output window's list of replaced files **if** I were to execute a "get latest" but I do not **actually** want to get them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on the top level folder in Source Control Explorer, select "Compare". Top option should be the server path e.g. `$/TeamProject/Myfolder` with the `latest version` selected in the dropdown. The bottom option should be `c:\MyWorkspace\TeamProject\Myfolder` this will do a compare with the latest version held in TFS with the files you have locally.  [image: Diff Screen 1][image: Diff Screen 2]

Or you could do the same thing using the `tf diff` command line tool.

Answer (score 6):

You can do a "preview get" from the command line:  `tf get /recursive /preview` will output the list of files that it would do a get of to update you to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with Powershell, you should be able to take this approach:

- Ensure Team Foundation Power Tools are installed
- You may need to re-run the installer as the TF Powershell cmdlets don't install by default
- Open up powershell in x86 mode (x64 causes weirdness with said cmdlets)
- Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell
- Navigate to your workspace root
- Get-TfsItemProperty * -recurse | where { $_.IsLatest -eq $false } | format-table
- Optionally, add "> staleList.txt" to pipe the output to a file.

Hope this works!